# Django static files served in docker found with findstatic but 404 from server

Tags: django, docker

I am running a Django/Angular/Docker build in development mode mounting the Angular build in the Django container to serve as static content. However, I am getting a 404 for all static files.

The weird thing is that running `python3 manage.py findstatic index.html` correctly finds the file.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run backend python3 manage.py findstatic index.html
Found 'index.html' here:
  /django/static/index.html
```

My settings are pretty straight forward.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
]
```

My urls --

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve

# root is served by angular index
url(r'^$', serve, kwargs={'path': 'index.html'}),
```

I am wondering how it can be found with findstatic but not found when performing an HTTP request?

This returns a 404 with the following message

`'index.html' could not be found`

EDIT:

So I pieced apart the FileSystemFinder and realized that the `os.path.exists(path)` call was failing even for a valid location. I can run `os.listdir('/app')` and get results

```
['app', '__init__.py', '__pycache__', 'setup.py', 'static', 'applications', 'manage.py', 'conf', 'wsgi.py', 'media']
```

This shows the static directory but when I run `os.listdir('/app/static')`  I get a file not found exception. If I run the command directly in the python terminal it works but from within the django app it fails. I am unsure what would cause a discrepancy with `os` commands.

Another EDIT:

Apparently, Django will not see new files put on the file system by default. I ended up using WhiteNoise so that it would see the files after they are generated by the angular container.

I think it is very strange behavior but since I have a working solution I am not going to continue attempting to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

html files are not member of static files. You should define template dir for django and put html files on there.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

define director of template in **DIRS** fields

Comment: These are not Django templates -- its a fully built angular app. But even so, the configuration works when running locally just not within a docker container so static files actually will serve up HTML files AFAIK.